# Instantiation of a composite object with lots of validation rules

Tags: oop, object, design-patterns, factory

I have an object that I would like to create. This object is composed of other objects that I don't want the client class to be responsible for creating. There are lots of validation rules that must pass before the object can be created.

So I would like to abstract away the creation of this complex object into a *"factory"* class. I have 2 questions really, the first is purely about semantics:-

1. What should I call the class which is creating my object? The [factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) pattern and [abstract factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) pattern are both related to abstracting away creation of concrete classes of *different types*. However, I'm creating an object of a single type, so using the term *factory* might be confusing?
2. Is this an appropriate solution? Are there any patterns/examples of this being done?

Thanks in advance for any help/guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use the term factory because we all use it in its broadest sense unless we use a more unique name like Factory Method design pattern or Abstract Factory design pattern.
2. Builder pattern is typically used if you have an object build process that should still be used if the same master steps should be used in creating different types of objects. But in your case you just have one type. So there's no need for a better solution since there's no special problem to solve. Just do the validation in the simplest form you can.

Comment: Builder pattern is also applicable when there are multiple steps to produce a single object (according to http://www.oodesign.com/builder-pattern.html), so I think I'm going to opt for builder. That way if I do end up splitting the type of the complex object I can use the same interface. Thanks very much for pointing me to the builder pattern!